# Saving a USER preference variable after logout

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my project I need to save the information about the user if he has submitted the form. What i am doing is saving it in `$_SESSION[]` variable when the user submit the form it is saved in session variable and by writing `if(!isset($_SESSION['page']))` i restrict the user from visiting that page but when i logout the whole session is destroyed. I once again is able to register but the user has already register, how to block the user from re-registering
This is the form

[image: This is the form]
when the form is submitted successfully I set `$_SESSION['personal_datas']=1;`

when user revisit his form after submitting[image: FORM AFTER SUBMITTING]

i check

```
 <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['personal_datas'])): ?>
      //display the form
  <?php else: ?>

   <div class="well">
     YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED THE FORM
   </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

But when i logout I revisit the page it displays the same unfilled form[image]

how to block the user from re-registering after re-login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is something unique to that the user enters into the form (such as a username or a personal identification number) you could store that in a database and every time the form is submitted check that the username (or whatever) provided is not already in the database.

Otherwise there is no way of permanently blocking a user from submitting the form again. Coockies can be deleted (and are browser specific). IP-adresses are not constant and many users can have the same IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cookie or some other form of semi-persistent storage. Session data expires anyway when you close the browser.

Comment: i want a permanent persistent storage variable  sort of global, since cookies are browser/computer dependent.

Comment: There's no such thing. I can always delete my cookies and I can always close my browser and you can't stop me.